# Running Total in SQL Client

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've read that in SQL Server 2012 you can easily get cumulative sums and was thinking about migrating my code to a later version of SQL server. I had the IT department push the latest SQL version (2014) through my software updates. However, what I expected to work, which is cumulative sum, still doesn't work in my SQL server. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

My SQL Code is giving me syntax errors and is literally the two lines below. If I remove the phrase "Order by sysdt", the code would work.

```
Select sum(paid) over (partition by clmnum order by sysdt )
From #temp
```

Comment: What would you expect the ORDER BY to do here? Why would you have to order a partition/window of records before summing it? You have to use `ORDER BY` with `RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()` but not `SUM()`

Comment: @JNevill .. the OP says `running total` and it is perfectly valid to use `order by` in a `SUM` window function.

Comment: syntax-wise there is nothing wrong with the query shown.

Comment: One thing I'm thinking is that maybe it's because I'm the only person with SQL Server 2014? Would it be necessary for whoever hosting the database to have SQL Server 2014 for me to run the query above?

Comment: at least version 2012

Comment: what does `select @@version` show?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5000.00 (Intel X86) 
 Dec 10 2010 10:56:29 
 Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 6.0 (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)

Comment: So I guess although I'm opening it using SQL server 2014 management studio, I'm still not on SQL Server 2014 ...

Comment: there you go...

Comment: FYI, to achieve something like SUM() OVER() in SQL Server prior to 2012, you could use an apply or a self-join (the partition/order would constitute the join conditions).